# How to convert columns to rows with Jsp and Mysql?

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

I have a table that gets dynamic data from a database. Naturally SQL will display the data in columns:

```html
<table style="border: 1px none ;" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Player_picture</td>
        <td>Player_Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>#Games</td>
        <td>Average_score</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to convert the columns into rows  and display in the browser like this:

```html
<table style="border: 1px none ; width: 703px;" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="1" rowspan="5" style="vertical-align: top; width: 173px;">Row#1
        <br>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 242px;">Player#1 (picture)</td>
      <td style="width: 270px;">Player#2 (picture)</td>
      <td style="width: 240px;">Player#3 (picture)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 242px;">Name</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 270px;">Name</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 240px;">Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 242px;">Age</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 270px;">Age</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 240px;">Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 242px;">#Games</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 270px;">#Games</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 240px;">#Games</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 242px;">Average_score</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 270px;">Average_score</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 240px;">Average_score</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="1" rowspan="5" style="vertical-align: top; width: 173px;">Row#2
        <br>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 242px;">Player#4 (picture)</td>
      <td style="width: 270px;">Player#5 (picture)</td>
      <td style="width: 240px;">Player#6 (picture)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 242px;">Name</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 270px;">Name</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 240px;">Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 242px;">Age</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 270px;">Age</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 240px;">Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 242px;">#Games</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 270px;">#Games</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 240px;">#Games</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 242px;">Average_score</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 270px;">Average_score</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 240px;">Average_score</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

SQL query:

```
<sql:query var="categoryPlayers" dataSource="jdbc/database">
    SELECT * FROM player WHERE category_id = ?
    <sql:param value="${pageContext.request.queryString}"/>
</sql:query>
```

Then display in JSP like this:

```
<c:forEach var="player" items="${categoryPlayers.rows}" varStatus="iter"></c:forEach>
```

Comment: Actually what output you want? what is your issue?

Comment: @ketan: I don't know how to convert dynamic rows to dynamic columns

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is generate each column's content in separate variables and then output the variables in your table:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

<%
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("player0");
    list.add("player1");

    String picture = "";
    String name = "";
    String age = "";
    String games = "";
    String avgSc = "";

    for (String s : list) {
        picture += "<td>" + s + "</td>";
        name += "<td>" + s + "</td>";
        age += "<td>" + s + "</td>";
        games += "<td>" + s + "</td>";
        avgSc += "<td>" + s + "</td>";
    }

%>

<table style="border: 1px none ; width: 438px;" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Player_picture</td>
        <%=picture%>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Player_Name</td>
        <%=name%>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Age</td>
        <%=age%>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">#Games</td>
        <%=games%>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">Average_score</td>
        <%=avgSc%>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But if there are hundreds of players in the database, It will be a very long night if I type every single one of them. The data is being retrieved automatically from the database with a query (just like in my post) and displayed in JSP with statements like `${player.name}`, `${player.age}`.  Would you still suggest using your method?

Comment: I gave you a working solution not the best one. You also need to do some work you know :) Usually when you have to deal with many records you need to implement a pagination mechanism.

Comment: Thank you mucho! I haven't tried your code yet... I'm trying to figure out how to use it so it is dynamically done when loading the table. So  that I don't have to enter all the players...

Comment: Well, you need to replace the List that I statically created with your data. You can achieve that by following this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html . Also, I would recommend integrating an MVC framework like Spring MVC for a more cleaner code and layer separation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this tricky way using JQuery. Check following.

```js
$("td:nth-child(3n)").after("<td class='newline'></td>");
```

```css
td{
  display:inline-block;
  }
.newline{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="border: 1px none ;" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Player_picture</td>
        <td>Player_Name</td>
        <td >Age</td>
        <td >#Games</td>
        <td>Average_score</td>
      <td >#Games</td>
      <td>Average_score</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```